# Как можно отредактировать текст в ячеке excel?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Вывожу результат в файл excel

```
             df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 20]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=0)
             df3 = pd.read_excel(self.filename2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 12]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],axis=0)

             result = df2.loc[df2.ne(df3.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
             result2 = df3.loc[df3.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]

             datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result2]], axis=1)

             datafr.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист', header=None, index=False)
             wb1 = load_workbook(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', read_only=False)
             sheet1 = wb1.active
             sheet1.column_dimensions['A'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['B'].width = 15
             sheet1.column_dimensions['C'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['D'].width = 140
             sheet1.column_dimensions['E'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['F'].width = 15
             sheet1.column_dimensions['G'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['H'].width = 140
             wb1.save(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx')
```

но в некоторых ячейках текст выводится во всю строку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как можно его отредактировать что бы он переносился в ячейке по строкам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42215933/5741205

Comment: @MaxU это то что нужно поставьте пожалуйста ссылку в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копия [ответа с англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52494457/5741205):

```
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

ws['A1'].alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
```

PS приведенный код должен работать для `openpyxl` >= 2.5.6

---

Для openpyxl >= 3.0.0 можно использовать [такой подход](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63140906/5741205):

```
import copy

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:      
        alignment = copy.copy(cell.alignment)
        alignment.wrapText=True
        cell.alignment = alignment
```